# how to edit custom css or less in Magento 2?

Tags: magento, custom-controls, magento2, magento-2.0

I had installed `magento 2.0.2` and also override the templates
I am stuck on a point that where do i write my `css` for my own styling.
How do i change the `css` of existing template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/design/frontend/namespace/yourtheme/web/css/source/_theme.less

start with changing the header background

```
.page-header {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/magento-2-header/101893#101893) also

Comment: i did this but no change happens.
i also deploy it but nothing changed.

Comment: did you set your theme in admin panel? after droply you check the checks file in pub/static the content is deployed

Comment: yes . and files are also deployed and i check code also

Comment: are you ding this custom theme? did the content come from your theme?

Comment: i have tried this also. 
To set the compilation mode, do the following:

    In the Magento Admin, navigate to Stores > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer.
    In the Store View drop-down field, select Default Config.
    Under Front-end development workflow, in the Workflow type field, select the compilation mode.
    To save the settings, click Save Config.
    Make sure that the same compilation mode is set for each configuration scope.

Comment: yes i have created my own new theme. parent is Magento/Luma

Comment: check the source they are coming from your theme or other theme.

Comment: styles-m.css styles-I.css and all other js css coming from my own theme from pub directory and styles.css is coming from 'pub/media' directory.

Comment: check that file your code is there? and also check the class name is correct?

Comment: its not helping. :( nothing changed in my theme. class name and directory everything is ok

Comment: i put this css in pub/media/styles.css and its working. is it also right way?

Comment: by doing this my back-end header also get black. :O

Comment: don't change this it not concerned with design.

Comment: do you have any guide or tutorial for this . i have a tutorial which i told you that is also not working. what should i do now.

Comment: there is no help yet available you can get help from here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html